# Get Data From Async Completion Handler

Tags: swift, asynchronous, core-location

Trying to get name of a city, while having latitude and longitude. 
Inside a model class `Location`, I'm using `reverseGeocodeLocation(location: , completionHandler: )` func that comes with CLGeocoder (part of CoreLocation).

```
func getLocationName() {

    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLatitude, longitude: currentLongitude)

    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
        guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {
            return
        }

        if let city = addressDict["City"] as? String {
            self.currentCity = city
            print(city)
        }
        if let zip = addressDict["ZIP"] as? String {
            print(zip)
        }
        if let country = addressDict["Country"] as? String {
            print(country)
        }
    })
}
```

However, in `ViewController`, after running the `getLocationName()`, the `location.currentCity` is `nil`, since the completion handler is async, and wasn't finished yet.

How can I make sure that the completion handler is finished running so I can access `location.currentCity` ?

Comment: Just access `location.currentCity` **in** the completion handler or add another completion handler to `getLocationName()` to return the data asynchronously.

Comment: You don't "make sure that the completion handler is finished running", you just do whatever you want to do with `location.currentCity` in the `completionHandler`

Comment: @vadian i need to access 'location.currentCity' in view controller, (outside of Location class) to updated the UI. Will it be better to add another completion handler so i'm not updating UI within a model class? 
Can you provide an example code how that new completion handler should be implemented?

Comment: @AndrewBrooke but I want to update my UI with location.currentCity in viewController and I don't have instances of my view controller within model class 'Location'. Should I create that instance, so i can do 'vcInstance.updateUI(currentCity)' somewhere within completion handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a closure as a function parameter in your getLocationName which
you can call inside the reverseGeocodeLocation closure.

```
func updateLocation(currentCity : String) -> Void
{
  print(currentCity)
}

func getLocationName(callback : @escaping (String) -> Void)
{

  let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
  let location = CLLocation(latitude: currentLatitude, longitude: currentLongitude)

  geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
     guard let addressDict = placemarks?[0].addressDictionary else {
        return
     }


     if let city = addressDict["City"] as? String
     {
         self.currentCity = city
         callback(city)

         print(city)
      }
      if let zip = addressDict["ZIP"] as? String {
         print(zip)
      }
      if let country = addressDict["Country"] as? String {
        print(country)
      }
   })
 }
```

In your ViewController...

```
getLocationName(callback: updateLocation)
```

Comment: not quite understand what is inside callback...
But you gave me some thoughts: 
How would I set 'currentCity' inside the callback? 
I can do that since callback will be implemented only after the completion handler. Right?

Comment: callback will be called when the completion handler is finished. you can set the currentCity inside the updateLocation function , see my example, and you can add that function in your ViewController.

Comment: got a bunch of errors: 
On 'func getLocationName(callback: (location:CLLocation) )' -  Cannot create a single-element tuple with an element label. 
On  'callback(location)' - Cannot call value of non-function type 'CLLocation'
and on  'print(location.currentCity)' - Value of type 'CLLocation' has no member 'currentCity'

Comment: now 'Use of unresolved identifier 'updateLocation' ' 
when i call for "Location.sharedInstance.getLocationName(updateLocation)" within view controller.

Comment: you need to add the updateLocation function in your ViewController or Location class.  Or you can just use any other name. It will be the function that will be called when reverseGeocodeLocation is completed.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function where location.currentCity is used, and call this function from the completion handler

So if your code looks like:

```
func foo() {
    var location
    getLocationName()
    print(location.currentcity) // nil
}
```

change it to:

```
func foo() {
    var location
    getLocationName()
}

func bar() {
    print(location.currentcity) // someplace
}
```

and call bar() from your completion handler

Comment: Thanks, that what commentors suggested too. 
However, bar( ) is located in another class (in ViewController). I want to updated the UI in bar( ). 
Should I create an instance of viewController and run 'updateUI( )' on it, while in Location model file?